# Reset Sitecore 10.2 control editor and inetpub folder in the root directory

Tags: sitecore-api, sia

I have installed `Sitecore 10.2` using `SIA` and I need to reset the control editor (so that all the templates and sites created get deleted) and the inetpub folder gets cleared up as well.

Is there a way to reset the Sitecore control editor and inetpub folder to its original form or do I need to delete everything and reinstall it?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution I can suggest:

1. If you have a backup of your Inetpub folder then you can restore that one and for the Sitecore content editor you can use the Vanilla Sitecore instance master database and restore that one.
2. Delete everything and reinstall the Sitecore instance again and make a practice to have a backup of your Sitecore Database and Inetpub folder before publishing and making any new changes to the code and DLL.

To delete everything and reinstall perform the below steps:

1. Stop the IIS and remove the configuration
2. Delete Sitecore Service
3. Delete the file system
4. Remove the entry from the host file
5. Delete the database
6. Stop Solr service
7. Delete the SOLR search indexes
8. Delete Certificates

for more details about the above-mentioned steps refer to the blog post: [Uninstall Sitecore Instance Manually](https://himmatsinghdulawat.blogspot.com/2022/03/uninstall-sitecore-instance-manually.html)

Comment: Thank you Himmat.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to reinstall everything. Here are the steps you can follow and it should work.

- Go to your `Sitecore Package`, which you downloaded from the `Sitecore` Website. i.e.
  [Sitecore 10.2 Package](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/102/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_102.aspx)
- Extract your `Sitecore Package`, i.e. `Sitecore 10.2.0 rev. 006766 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.4.0-r5).zip`
- Open the extracted folder and you will get another zip called
  `Sitecore 10.2.0 rev. 006766 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip`. Extract this
  Zip.
- Under this extracted folder, you will get your `Sitecore Vanilla` instance inside the `Content -> Website` folder.
- Also you will get all the Fresh databases here.
- You can replace your `inetpub` folder and restore the databases to
  get your fresh `Sitecore instance`.

Also, don't forget to keep a backup of everything you have. I think you also need to replace your `Web.Config` after replacing everything.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Sumit